# Mixed saying / witty remark about remarks

Tags: idioms, old-english, gerund-vs-infinitive

I need to mix

> To err is human, to persist [...] is diabolical

with a joke about too much remarking.

The result should be

> To err is human, to persist in remarking is diabolical.

Should I change it in "persist in remarks"? Would it give a more...*as-the-saying-goes* allure?

Comment: Know when you're beaten.

Comment: I'm not catching the sense of the joke, in that I'm not making a connection between "err" and "remark".  Could you clarify?

Comment: So something along the lines of "To err is human, to persist in quoting proverbs is diabolical"?

Comment: That one's nice! but I'm working on a translation here, so I can't change that much the meaning :<
|| 
@DukeZhou Character A says something wrong for the billionth (hyperbole) tyme, char. B corrects him as he always does; A semiquotes the saying implying that B his "diabolical"

Comment: @Kyōka  ic.  It definitely works better with the context.  Is this a dramatic or narrative?  (It reminds me of the type of pithy remark one might find in a Noel Coward play for some reason;)

Comment: It's something...erm...mixed? At the moment the reader gets only the comic side, but later we find out that there's more to it. There's the word "gore" in the title, tho — annnd that's the name of the main character, so I can't really separate the content from the dialogic structure (the author choose to call the parts of the narration "scenes", in the first draw, not joking ^^" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's strictly between "remarks" and "remarking", I'd definitely choose the latter.

I can't give you a technical reason, since my preference is based on the aesthetics. *(Possibly this is because the present tense lends it a more active feel, which is to say, it makes the line "more present" and increases the impact.)*